# Large deviation for gaussian distribution

Tags: probability-theory, large-deviation-theory

Given a random variable $X$ that is $N(0,1)$ distributed and a sequence $(X_i)$ of iid distributed $N(0,1)$ random variables(copies of $X$) and I am supposed to calculate $P(X \ge 5)$ by means of large deviations.

Hence, I calculated the rate function $\gamma^*(l) = \frac{l^2}{2}$. And now I am stuck. Is the random variable $Z:=\frac{e^{-\gamma^*(5)} }{(2\pi)^{\frac{n}{2}}}e^{- \frac{X_1^2+...+X_n^2}{n}}$ now my estimator for this event, I am a little bit confused. Basically, I want to apply this theory here : [wikipedia reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_deviations_theory#Large_deviations_for_sums_of_independent_random_variables)

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: What's $X$....?

Comment: sorry, the sequence is a copy of $X$.

Comment: Somehow it doesn't make sense to "calculate $\mathbb{P}(X \geq 5)$ by means of large deviations". Large deviation theory is always about the exponential decay of probabilities, i.e. estimates of the form $$\mathbb{P}(X_n \in B) \sim \exp(-n I(B));$$ this means in particular that the probabiliy converges to $0$. As, obviously, $\mathbb{P}(X \geq 5)>0$, this doesn't make sense at all. Using Markov's inequality, we can find an (upper bound) for the probability, but this doesn't has much to do with large deviations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is standard normal, then, when $x\to+\infty$,
$$
P(X\geqslant x)\sim\frac{\mathrm e^{-x^2/2}}{x\sqrt{2\pi}},
$$
in the sense that the ratio of the LHS and the RHS converges to $1$. For $x=5$ this suggests that $P(X\geqslant5)$ might be close to
$$
\frac{\mathrm e^{-12.5}}{5\sqrt{2\pi}}\approx2.97\cdot10^{-7},
$$
while the exact value is
$$
P(X\geqslant5)\approx2.87\cdot10^{-7}.
$$
Not an ounce of large deviations here. Large deviations in this context would yield the cruder estimate
$$
P(X\geqslant x)=\exp\left(-\frac12x^2+o(x^2)\right),
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\log P(X\geqslant x)}{x^2}=-\frac12.
$$

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're after is

$$\Pr(\bar X > 5),$$

correct?

Note that for standard normal distributions the cumulant generating function is

$$\lambda(\theta) = \log E\bigl(\exp(\theta X_1)\bigr)
 = \log \Bigl[ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(\theta x) \exp(-x^2/2) dx \big/ \sqrt{2\pi}\Bigr] =
 \theta^2/2.$$

So the Legendre-Fenchel transformation value is $I(5)=12.5$.

Hence

$$\Pr( \bar X >5) \approx \exp(-12.5n).$$

If that's not what you're after then please clarify.

Comment: mhmm. I want to estimate $P(X\ge 5)$ with the Legendre transformation so depending on what you mean by $\bar{X}$ you may be right, but I don't understand why the result should depend on $n$?

Comment: I would say that this is **not** what the OP is looking for. Because $\bar{X} := \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \sim N(0,1/n)$ is not distributed as $X \sim N(0,1)$.